# Service does not install through installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service, wix, windows-installer

I have been provided some services and i have to create a installer to install these window services and start these services after successful installation. Services are being installed through command prompt. but through installer i am getting this error

> Service "RedBoxReportSchedulerService"(RedBoxReportSchedulerService) failed to start. verify
>   that you have sufficient privileges to start the system services

I did check the privilege and changed through service properties but no success.

Following is the code for installing just one service.

```
<Component Id ="RedBoxReportSchedulerServiceInstall" Directory="REPORTSCHEDULER" Guid="*">
    <File Id='ReportSchedulerServiceEXE' Name="RedBox Report Scheduler.exe" DiskId='1' Source="../Updatedir/Report Scheduler/ReportScheduler.exe"  KeyPath='yes'/>
    <ServiceInstall
    Id="ReportScheduler_ServiceInstaller"
    Type="ownProcess"
    Name="RedBoxReportSchedulerService"
    DisplayName="RedBox Report Scheduler"
    Description="RedBox Report Scheduler Service"
    Start="auto"
    Account="LocalSystem"
    Arguments=" /start RedBoxReportSchedulerService"
    ErrorControl="normal">
      <util:PermissionEx  User="Everyone" ServicePauseContinue="yes" ServiceQueryStatus="yes" ServiceStart="yes" ServiceStop="yes" ServiceUserDefinedControl="yes" />
    </ServiceInstall>
    <ServiceControl Id="Start_ReportScheduler_Service" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Name="RedBoxReportSchedulerService" Wait="no" />
  </Component>
```

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong. I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name in ServiceControl must be the same as in the ServiceInstall, and it's not. You are trying to start a non-existing service called RedBoxReportSchedulerService. The actual installed service might start successfully if you go to the services control panel applet to start it.

So that is the obvious issue. For completeness, if the service still doesn't start then move on to these:

If the service has any tracing diagnostics then turn them on to see if the service is starting and crashing or otherwise not responding to the start. There's a protocol involved, and the service must respond within (I think) about 30 seconds. Diagnostics will tell you if the service actually started.

The service might be missing dependencies. It's rare for a code file to be completely self-contained - it may need C++ runtime support, other Dlls from your company, .NET framework versions etc. After the install the service is still installed, yes? If so, manually start it from the services control panel and see if it starts.